# JavaScript Object overriding

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to create an array of objects. The object contains 3 attributes, 2 of which will be generated from 2 pre populated arrays.

The expected result is an array of 3 distinct objects.

The problem is when I populate the array with the objects I get 3 duplicates of the same object.

Here is a console log of the problem. It seems that when I console log each object I get the distinct value, but when I push them into the array, I get a duplicated value.

[image]

```
  let tVersionobjArr = [];
  let temtempObjholderpObj = { key: " ", value: " ", dbVersion: " " };
  for (let j = 0; j < container.length; j++) {
    if (container[j] !== undefined) {
      console.log(temtempObjholderpObj);
      temtempObjholderpObj.key = j;
      temtempObjholderpObj.value = test2[j];
      temtempObjholderpObj.dbVersion = container[j];
      // tVersionobjArr[j] = temtempObjholderpObj;
      tVersionobjArr.push(temtempObjholderpObj);
    }
  }
```

The 2 external arrays are just string arrays.

Comment: You only have one object. If you want new objects, create new objects.

Comment: TL;DR in case that wasn't enough: create the object in the loop, not outside of it.

Comment: Move the `temtempObjholderpObj = { … }` inside the loop